# In C#, how do I remove a property from an ExpandoObject?

Tags: c#, expandoobject

Say I have this object:

```
dynamic foo = new ExpandoObject();
foo.bar = "fizz";
foo.bang = "buzz";
```

How would I remove `foo.bang` for example?

I don't want to simply set the property's value to null--for my purposes I need to remove it altogether.  Also, I realize that I could create a whole new ExpandoObject by drawing kv pairs from the first, but that would be pretty inefficient.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Cast the expando to `IDictionary<string, object>` and call [`Remove`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb356469.aspx):

```
var dict = (IDictionary<string, object>)foo;
dict.Remove("bang");
```

Comment: i know this was quite a while ago, but found this today and it helped me get out of an issue where i had to remove all the properties from an dynamic/ExpandoObject contained in a list. it was a literally a one liner (to match the OP, using bang!!): 

bangItems.All(x => ((IDictionary<string, object>) x).Remove("bang"));

Comment: The code in the answer ```bangItems.All(x => ((IDictionary<string, object>) x).Remove("bang"));``` ain't working right? Heads-up that someone might get confused.

Answer (score 35):

You can treat the [`ExpandoObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx) as an [`IDictionary<string, object>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4ys34ea.aspx) instead, and then remove it that way:

```
IDictionary<string, object> map = foo;
map.Remove("Jar");
```

Comment: need to remove the member 'Jar' form Foo.. not Foo it self..,

Comment: @Dhana: So change `Foo` to `Jar` :) I've updated the example, but if you understand the way the answer is meant to work, it shouldn't be hard to fix it up yourself...

Answer (score 16):

MSDN Example:

```
dynamic employee = new ExpandoObject();
employee.Name = "John Smith";
((IDictionary<String, Object>)employee).Remove("Name");
```

Answer (score 8):

You can cast it as an `IDictionary<string,object>`, and then use the explicit [Remove](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd630196.aspx) method.

```
IDictionary<string,object> temp = foo;
temp.Remove("bang");
```