# Remove property and it's value from dynamic object in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, object

In `PHP` we can remove one property and its value from the object simply with this code:

```
$foo->bar = "Something";
unset($foo->bar);
```

I want to do this in C#.

Imagine that the object is:

```
var a = new {foo = bar, one = "one"}
```

How I can remove `foo` from the object?

Comment: For anyone landing here a year and a half later: In this specific case, dynamic types are a good fit. Take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14491577/166848

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Types are defined at compile-time, so there's no removing of properties, not in c#. An anonymous type is a type just like classes that you create; it's just that the name is hidden from you.

The closest you can get to your answer is to define a new type that omits the property you wish to remove:

```
var b = new { one = a.one };
```