# API Controller dynamically filter returned fields in ASP .NET Core and EF Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a REST endpoint returning a customer with some nested data. For example the orders related to this customer. In order to minimize the amount of requests by the client i want to dynamically include the nested data if asked for.

This data is retrieved from the database using EF Core. My database model looks like this:

```cs
public class DbCustomer
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<DbOrder> Orders { get; set; }
}
public class DbOrder
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

---

Then i map this database model into data transfer objects (DTO), where i already strip out fields which never should be returned to clients.

```cs
public class CustomerDTO
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<OrderDTO> Orders { get; set; }
}
public class OrderDTO
{
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

---

A `GET`  request including orders may look like this: `GET example.com/customer?id=15&fields=orders,otherfield`. This is my corresponding controller action:

```cs
[HttpGet("customer")]
public async Task<CustomerDTO> GetCustomer(string Id, string fields)
{
    DbCustomer customer = await _ctx.Customers
        //Only query Orders if it is inside "fields"?
        .Include(c => c.Orders)
        .AsNoTracking()
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.Id = Id);
    //Or filter here based on provided "fields"?
    CustomerDTO customerDTO = customer.MapToDTO();
    return customerDTO;
}
```

One Solution could be different DTO´s (`CustomerDTO`, `CustomerWithOrderDTO`) for all possible optional fields, but this would result in many DTO´s if i have more nested fields.
Are there any dynamically solutions to opt-in those fields if requested by the client?

Comment: Please note that `[asp.net]` is a .NET Framework tag. I've fixed it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ExpandoObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.dynamic.expandoobject?view=net-5.0) to add the required properties, or remove the not required properties.

EDIT:

[How to add property with ExpandoObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938397/dynamically-adding-properties-to-an-expandoobject)

[How to remove property with ExpandoObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14491577/in-c-how-do-i-remove-a-property-from-an-expandoobject)

EDIT 2:

For the EF Core I believe this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54549506/select-only-specific-fields-with-linq-ef-core) solve your problem.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more please?
And how does this help with EF Core?

Comment: My mistake, I forgot the EF Core solution. The ExpandoObject will solve your DTO problem.
For the EF Core I believe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54549506/select-only-specific-fields-with-linq-ef-core) can solve the problem. It's quite an interesting way to select, I myself have never used it, but probably once needed and simply ignored it.